# Azure Data Factory - Data Flow - Set Variable

Tags: azure-data-factory

Within my pipeline I have a small data flow activity that reads a value out of a JSON file that I would like to use back in the main flow.

From withing the data flow I would like to set a variable with this value, however I've not found a way to do that.

So how do I set a variable with a new value from within a 'data flow' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every data flow activity needs to have a Sink. Sink that data value from your data flow results into a destination store (i.e. Blob store). You can then read that value from your data flow in a subsequent Lookup activity to load it into a pipeline variable.

Comment: isnt there any other way around this? I have a jwt token that I get from a flow and need to pass it to another flow as variable or something. don't want to write that to sink

Answer (score 1):

Now we can set values in a dataflow without the need of using sink to load a file in Blob store and using extra activities to read it. Check `Cached lookup` documentation:

[Cache Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#cache-sink)
[Cached lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#cached-lookup)

In the `Sink` we can select `Cache` instead of Dataset...

[image]

Then we can use that value in any of the other activities:

like `mySinkName#outputs()[myRowNumber].myColumnName`

[image]